# i integrated tinymce in Node + expressjs app

Tags: node.js, express, tinymce, ejs

i integrated tinymce into Node + expressjs web app but when I create a post the post will display in show.ejs in HTML tags instead of plain text.
my post will look like this:

```
<p><strong>INTRODUCTION: </strong>what is life?  but there are other questions we must answer.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>What is human life like compared to God&rsquo;s? How can God&rsquo;s ?</p>
```

is there any way I can sanitize the post to remove the HTML tags

Comment: TinyMCE is an HTML editor whose sole job is to create HTML content. If you do not want content with HTML markup, using TinyMCE might not be the best option for you. But, do you really want to remove the HTML tags, or do you want the HTML itself to be *rendered* (rather than the markup displayed on the page)? For example, do you want to remove the `<strong>` tag, or do you want the text within them to appear bold?

Comment: Thanks, @Lincoln. I want the HTML to be rendered rather than the markup been displayed on the page. the markup displaying on the page makes it very hard to read. i followed all the steps I found here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/expressjs/ I watched some tutorial on Youtube I didn't see the HTML markup display on the page,

Comment: I think i solved the problem, i changed the ejs tags from <%=%> to <%-%>